PHP 8.3 Typed Class Constants - Closures
This article https://php.watch/versions/8.3/typed-constants#supported_types affirms that
PHP 8.3 allows us to declare typed constants of Closure type.
But I could not find any reference on how to do it.
Is it a mistake, or is there the possibility to have closures as constants? How can it be done?
I tried to guess the syntax on my own, but with no results:
class ClassWithTypedConstants
{
    public const int INTEGER = 1;
    public const int|string INTEGER_OR_STRING = 1;
    public const \Closure CLOSURE = () => {};
}


Hmm... my gut says that the article isn't correct. Looking at the discussions here, here and here, the vote, and the rfc, I see no mention of closures. In the area where the RFC talks about callables it references the typed properties RFC which does have a section related to closuers, and I wonder if that confused the author.

I think the article was only trying to point out that \Closure is an allowed type. But you cannot have a constant with such type because there isn't a possible value that could be assigned to it. It's just my guess though.

The const keyword only supports limited expressions, but the define function supports arbitrary expressons, so you can use it to define a constant first and then assign it to a class constant.
define('CL', function () { echo "hello\n"; });

class Foo
{
    public const \Closure CL = CL;
}

This doesn't make much sense, I agree with the article just pointing out that Closure is an allowed type.
BTW if you try to invoke the constant, you need to wrap it in parenthesis.
(Foo::CL)();


It seems it works: https://3v4l.org/F2VKn#v8.3.6
